# Calling multiple procedures in one procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have three procedures that I need to call in specific order in one procedure. How can I do that?

Lets say that one procedure is called `proc_log`. Other three procedures that must be called in proc_log are: `insert_header, insert_mapping, insert_item` (strictly in that order).

Could someone give a code sample on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure; one after another.

```
create or replace procedure proc_log is
begin
  insert_header;
  insert_mapping;
  insert_time;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as shown below:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_log
    AS
   BEGIN    
        BEGIN
            insert_header ();
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                raise_application_error( -20001,'In insert_header' );
        END;

        BEGIN
            insert_mapping ();
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                raise_application_error(-20002,'In insert_mapping');
        END;

        BEGIN
            insert_item ();
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                raise_application_error(-20003,'In insert_item');
        END;

    EXCEPTION 
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001,'In proc_log');
    END;
```